# Hide IonicLoading after for cycle

Tags: ionic-framework

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$scope.auth = function (s) {

    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    })

    if (s=0) {
        console.log("Alert!")
    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            Data.update("my params").then(function (result) {
                console.log(result)
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Data.update() is an http request in services.js file.

I would like display ionicLoading until for cycle ends. If I put $ionicLoading.hide() after the cycle nothing happens because the loader shows and hides immediately.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$q.all` to fire multiple promises at the same time and do something once all of them are resolved:

```js
var promiseArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
  promiseArray.push(Data
    .update("my params")
    .then(function (result) {
       console.log(result)
     }, function (err) {
       console.log(err);
    });
  });
}

$q
  .all(promiseArray)
  .then(function() {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide loading at last iteration of for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        Data.update("my params").then(function (result) {
            if(i==s){
               $ionicLoading.hide();
            }
            console.log(result)
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```